# Is there any way to declare the name of the variable then the type

Tags: c++, types, casting, void

I have enable to the user choosing the type of data he wants to use, for example if he wants to use long or double etc.
I would like to declare first the name of the variable then set its type. Is it possible in C++?

Comment: If I got you correctly then it is impossible in C++ world.

Comment: Types are a compile time construct. They do not really exist after your program has been compiled and cannot be changed at run time.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why don't you just create a variable of the appropriate type after the user makes a choice? Could you clarify?

Comment: @TylerM. Is there anything like Number class in Java which is supertype for any numbers including Double and Integer? I cannot casue it gives 10 times code.

Comment: @RobertKilar yes, `boost::variant` or `VARIANT` does pretty much that.

Comment: here it is: `auto x = int( 42 )`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf he won't be able to dynamically change that type based on user input at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to do this:

```
declare variable;

// in the program:
variable = (int) anotherVariable;
```

Short answer:

## No

Long answer:

a `void *` does exactly this, it needs to be explicitly converted to a different type before dereferencing. But this is not possible on variables that are not `void *`s.

```
void *variable = NULL;
int someIntVariable = 100;
int *someIntPointer = NULL;
variable = &someIntVariable;
someIntPointer = (int *)variable;
.. // but this seems unncessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if you're on Windows) or something similar on other platforms. The point of `VARIANT` is that it's a union that is capable of storing all kinds of data types but only 1 particular type at a given time. This way you can define a new generic variable type (`VARIANT`) ahead of time and then adapt its internal type at run-time, depending on user choice.

Using something like `VARIANT` comes at a price, though, since every operation that you do on it will have to check if the operation is correct for the current underlying type. `VARIANT` also uses more memory since the union has its own overhead (see the definition for details).

You may want to wrap variant operations in a class to simplify its usage. The nice thing about `VARIANT` as opposed to `void*` is that it gives you a lot more type safety and the code becomes a lot more readable.

Edit: as another answer pointed out, `boos::variant` is for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html), or, if you need only PODs, `union`. However keep in mind that this complicates many things.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum VariantType {
   USER_INT, USER_DOUBLE
};

union Variant {
   int i;
   double d;
}

int main() {
   VariantType type;
   Variant data;
   type = getUserDataType();
   switch(type) {
   case USER_INT:
      data.i = 42;
      break;
   case USER_DOUBLE:
      data.d = 42.0;
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

...or use some ready Variant implmementation.